# why is "t" imported as turtle not working inside the for loop inside while loop neither is "new_turtle" working and its turtle we have to use there

Tags: python

```
import random
import turtle as t

is_race_on = False
screen = t.Screen()
screen.setup(width=500, height=400)
user_bet = screen.textinput(title="Make your bet", prompt="Which tutle will win the race? Enter a colour ")
colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple"]
y_axis = -100
all_turtles = []

for colour in colors:
    new_turtle = t.Turtle(shape="turtle")
    new_turtle.color(colour)
    new_turtle.pu()
    new_turtle.goto(x=-230, y=y_axis)
    all_turtles.append(new_turtle)
    y_axis += 50


if user_bet:
    is_race_on = True

while is_race_on:
    for turtle in all_turtles:
        distance = random.randint(0, 10)
        turtle.fd(distance)


screen.exitonclick()
```

I was expecting the turtle.forward() should be t.forward() or new_turtle.fd(), but those are not working and it is saying not defined

Comment: Your code works just fine.  I'm guessing you tried to run the file without saving your changes.  However, just because it works doesn't mean it's right -- people reading your code will expect the turtle module to be called `turtle`.  Traditions are there to reduce the chance for errors.

Comment: yeah, it works, but inside the for loop which is inside the while loop, why is new_turtle.forward() not working, like is it not meant to be new_turtle.forward()

Comment: Don't worry, I now understand.